# Why do withdraw and drawings methods in account class?

Tags: java

Imagine you have a bank problem

You are designing classes

At that time you have 3 classes;bank,account and customer

Why do we have to put withdraw and drawings methods into the account class? Why not customer class is not proper?

Answer (score 1):

A customer could have multiple accounts at one bank. If you call the withdraw method on a customer with two accounts, which account to you want to use? Also the amount of money is stored in the account, so reducing it is a method the account is responsible for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be really good for you to check this out [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

So why it would be preferable to put the "withdrawal" method in an "account" class instead of a "customer" class is because withdrawal is activity that is carried out on an account, rather than on a customer.

Comment: and another question is that why should i declare Account myAccount=new Account in customer class instead of test class?